# ¿Como refrescar un datatable y no toda la ventana?

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap, datatables

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto con bootstrap, php pdo y mysql, tengo un datatable que lee desde mysql, tengo un botón que dice "Nuevo Ingreso", ya hace el ingreso pero quiero refrescar o actualizar el datatable para que cargue los nuevos datos sin tener que actualizar toda la pagina.

Cuando haga el nuevo ingreso desde el botón solo se refresque la sección del datatable y muestre el nuevo ingreso.

Por ahora lo hago refrescando toda la pagina con un window.location.href luego de recibir el ok desde el jquery que hizo el ingreso a la base de la nueva fila.

Ya lo carga usando la respuesta de @Maykol-Rivas, pero dejo de funcionar una acción, como veran la tabla tiene los datos y en la ultima columna tiene unas acciones, por ahora esta la accion de "crear historia"

```
               <tr class="odd gradeX">
                <td id="pacedula">14</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>5</td>                      
                <td class="center">
                <li class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></li>
                <li class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></li>
                <li class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></li>
                <li class="glyphicon icon-i-outpatient crearhistoria btn"></li>
                </td>
              </tr>
```

Que la llamo asi desde el js,

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    cargar_datos();
    });

   function cargar_datos(){
    $.ajax({
    url: "php/mod_listar_datos.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {opcion:1},
    success: function(data) {
             // En caso de que se ejecute
             $('#tblPacientes > tbody').html(data);
       }
    });
   }


 $(".crearhistoria").click(function(){
      var $cedula = $(this).closest("tr").find("#pacedula").text();       
      $.ajax({
       url : 'php/mod_cre_his_paciente.php',
       type: "POST",
       method: "post",
       data : "cedula="+ $cedula,
       beforeSend: function(){              
$('#labelMensajes').fadeIn(250).html('Enviando').delay(2500).fadeOut(250);
  },
success:function(v) {
      if(v==5){                  
         $('#labelMensajespacientes').fadeIn(250).html('No se ha enviado cedula, intentelo nuevamente').delay(10000).fadeOut(250);
         //window.location.href = "ad_docentes.php";
      }else if(v==4){  
         $('#labelMensajespacientes').fadeIn(250).html('Ya se ha creado la histora Clinica del paciente con CI'+ $cedula).delay(5000).fadeOut(250);                 
      }else if(v==3){  
         $('#labelMensajespacientes').fadeIn(250).html('Se ha creado la histora Clinica').delay(2500).fadeOut(250);    
         window.location.href="hclinica.php";           
      }else{         

$('#labelMensajespacientes').fadeIn(250).html(v).delay(2500).fadeOut(250);
      }
},
      error: function() {

$('#labelMensajespacientes').fadeIn(250).html('Error: no se puedo realizar el ingreso').delay(2500).fadeOut(250);      
}});});
```

Pero ahora no logra hacer nada esa función, así lo hacia antes pero con lo que hice ahora no funciona.

Answer (score 2):

Si cargas de nuevo el HTML, los elementos DOM son sustituídos, y a los nuevos no se les ha asignado el evento. Vuelve a asignarlos después de asignar el HTML de nuevo. Mejor con off/on ya que así evitas duplicar llamadas.

```
$(".crearhistoria").off('click');$(".crearhistoria").on('click', function() { ... };
```

Espero sea de ayuda

Answer (score 0):

como comenta el otro amigo, intenta hacer una petición AJAX que actualice tu datatable, algo asi:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "ruta_de_mi_archivo_php_donde_haremos_la_consulta.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {veruser:1},
        success: function(data) {
                 // En caso de que se ejecute
                 $('#mi_tabla > tbody').html(data);
        }
 });
```

Ahora, en ruta_de_mi_archivo_php_donde_haremos_la_consulta.php deberias tener algo asi

```
if($_POST['veruser']==1){
     //Aqui haces tu consulta para ver todos los usuarios.
     // Pero en el while que harás, deberas retornarlo con lo valores en tr y td
     //Ejemplo
     while($row = mysql_fecth_array($resulconsulta)){
           $usuarios .= '<tr>
                             <td>'.$row['id'].'<td>
                             <td>'.$row['nombre'].'<td>
                             <td>'.$row['apellido'].'<td>
                         </tr>' 
     }
     echo $usuarios;
}
```

De esta manera retornarás directamente el contenido a llenar en el body de la tabla de usuarios, o donde quieras, de hecho puedes hacer lo que quieras, y claro, sin actualizar la pagina. :) Suerte

Comment: Tengo un problema, como limpio lo que ya tiene table para que no vuelva a seguir agregando, es decir se van duplicando todo.

Comment: Cuando asignas los resultados a la tabla usando `$('#mi_tabla > tbody').html(data);` la propiedad `.html()` borra el contenido actual y lo reemplaza por el nuevo, en este caso, el que esta en la variable  `data`

Comment: Ya note esto, ahora tengo otro problema, ya logro cargar todo, pero en un columna tenia unos iconos con acciones sobre la fila, antes de cargarlo así funcionaba, pero ahora no. Actualizo la pregunta para agregar mas código a que lo veas.

Comment: Okay, puedes agregar al `<li>` esto: `onClick="CrearHistoria(this)"` luego cambia tu evento `$(".crearhistoria").click(function(){});` por una función `function CrearHistoria(d){}` donde `d` reemplazara a tu `this`, es decir que donde tengas `$(this)` ahora será `$(d)`

Te dejo un ejemplo básico aquí [https://jsfiddle.net/54g9f7hu/] donde también metí una función para borrar la fila borrar, puedes jugar con el código

Comment: Con lo que me indicas funciona bien, pero ahora otro problema en el datatable de bootstrap (Bootstrap v3.3.7), no me deja buscar, cuando elimino el texto en el campo buscar no se vuelven a llenar los textos.

Comment: Tienes alguna forma de mostrarme como quedo tu código? aunque sea un demo en [https://jsfiddle.net/] con datos staticos

Comment: Lo he subido a un host que tengo puedes verlo acá, http://www.fabisaconfecciones.com/hampi/pacientes.php  esta hecho con pdo

Comment: Entiendo lo que te sucede, busquemos otra forma, yo tambien uso datatables, solo que de una manera un poco similar, te dejo la referencia para que veas:  (i64.tinypic.com/4t7epj.png) (i68.tinypic.com/dzcmcp.png) (i65.tinypic.com/30sg4jn.png)

Comment: De que otra manera puedo cargar el data table?

Answer (score 0):

Ya te dieron una respuesta que te sugiere servir código `HTML` desde el servidor. Otra opción (y más estándar) es servir los registros como `JSON`.

> Suponiendo que haces una consulta con LIMIT para obtener los últimos 10 registros

```
$json = array();
// convierte el resultset a array
// para convertirlo a JSON
for($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
  $json[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

**NOTA**: debes tener en cuenta el orden en la query.

En tu código JavaScript, obtienes los registros en `JSON` por AJAX.

```
$.getJSON('/get_records.php', function(records) {
  $('#tabla').empty(); // limpia la tabla -> forma "fácil"
  records.forEach(function (record, i) {
    const cell = document.querySelector(`table td:nth-child(${i})`);
    // obtiene la clave (columna) del JSON para obtener el valor
    let key = Object.keys(record)[0];
    cell.textContent = record[key];
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Propuesta 1**: Al usar el plugin DataTable, tambien usar la **API** que provee

Cuando entro a: http://www.fabisaconfecciones.com/hampi/pacientes.php

Archivo: **tables.js**
- Aqui podrias hacer los siguientes cambios:

```
$('#tblPacientes').DataTable({
  deferLoading: 0, // Indicamos que la carga inicial se hace manual
  serverSide: true, // Indicamos que todos tipo de proceso se hace en el Backend
  ajax: {
    url: 'php/mod_listar_datos.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: function(params) {
      // Aqui deberas analizar lo que DT envia
      // y de ser necesario modificarlo a tu antojo
      // IMPORTANTE: param.draw deber ser enviado y devuelto.
      return params;
    },
    dataSrc: function(response) {
      // Idealmnete el servidor devolveria una respuesta JSON
      // por lo que response seria un objeto
    }
  }
});
```

Archivo: **pacientes.js**
- Aqui recomiendo eliminar la función *cargar_datos*
- Y en los lugares donde es llamada, reemplazarlo por:

```
$('#tblPacientes').DataTable().ajax.reload();
```

Mas info: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax

**Propuesta 2**: No usar el plugin DataTable y hacer todo a mano.

Comment: Voy a probarlo de esta manera

Comment: Lo intente como lo dijiste pero no carga nada y da error en el reload, me sale que no esta definida la función.

Comment: @AlldesignWeb, disculpa, se ve que no me di cuenta que el resultado de `'php/mod_listar_datos.php'` es `HTML`. Mi respuesta solo sirve si el resultado es un `JSON`.

Answer (score 0):

Hay una forma de manejar ajax con datatable, y pienso que es la mejor forma de trabajar la librería.

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "data/arrays.txt"
    } );
} );
```

html:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            ....
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

fuente: https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html

también puedes encontrar por paginación, añadiendo campos como "total_paginas", "cantidad_registros", "siguientes"...